# Ubuntu Studio 21.04

Tags: 21.04

I've been trying to install 21.04 and it gets to 78% and fails with error "apt install -y --no-upgrade -o Options:=--ignore-time-conflict shim-signed failed to finish in 300 seconds"

Any Ideas ??

Bob

Comment: Are you, by chance, on a school/corporate/enterprise network that may, for example, require the use of a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of this error but maybe try to reinstall the OS on the USB or the disk. This might help also it's a good idea if still getting the issue to use another USB stick or DVD disk.
Sometimes when installing an OS to a USB stick might go wrong but the second try should most likely work. It might be corrupted or something.
Do you have secure install OS on because sometimes the BIOS will block you from installing Linux it's easy to turn off in the BIOS though.
Thank Jonathan Steadman.

Comment: Thank you.. Had secure boot on and didn't see it  Thanks again Bob

Comment: @user3416835 No problem. :)